# AWS Async Response routing to success-channel for sqs-outbound-channel-adapter

Tags: spring-integration, amazon-sqs, spring-integration-aws

I have registered an `AsyncHandler` and also added a `success-channel` to an SQS outbound flow. The `success-channel` has a `int:logging-channel-adapter` endpoint. However I am not able to see any logs from this adapter. The `AsyncHandler` is able to receive the ***call-backs*** but nothing on the `success-channel`.
In the `SqsMessageHandler` I see that we are setting an ***output channel*** in the `obtainAsyncHandler` method, but I did not see the `success-channel` set anywhere. Am I missing something?
I would prefer using the success and failure channels and not AsyncHandler call-back Impl to avoid having AWS specific code in my classes.

Also my  `<int-aws:sqs-outbound-channel-adapter>` is inside a `<int:chain>` which has no output channel, since the flow ends when the message is sent.

EDIT - Added Config
This is the only way I can get it to log the callback.

```
    <int:channel id="chainChannel" />
    <int:channel id="successChannel" />
    <bean class="ServiceTransformer" id="serviceTransformer" />
    <int:chain input-channel="serviceChannel" id="sendToServiceSqsChain" output-channel="chainChannel">
        <int:transformer ref="serviceTransformer" method="transform" />
        <int:header-filter header-names="config" />
        <int-aws:sqs-outbound-channel-adapter sqs="amazonSQS" queue="some-queue" async-handler="sqsPublishCallbackHandler" success-channel="successChannel"/>
    </int:chain>

    <int:logging-channel-adapter log-full-message="true" channel="chainChannel" />
```

***Here I can just use the same channel in both chain (outbound channel) and sqs-outbound (success-channel)***

Unable to get it to work like below:

```
        <int:channel id="successChannel" />
        <bean class="ServiceTransformer" id="serviceTransformer" />
        <int:chain input-channel="serviceChannel" id="sendToServiceSqsChain" >
            <int:transformer ref="serviceTransformer" method="transform" />
            <int:header-filter header-names="config" />
            <int-aws:sqs-outbound-channel-adapter sqs="amazonSQS" queue="some-queue" async-handler="sqsPublishCallbackHandler" success-channel="successChannel"/>
        </int:chain>
    
        <int:logging-channel-adapter log-full-message="true" channel="successChannel" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<int-aws:sqs-outbound-channel-adapter>` component is one-way, therefore there is no `outputChannel` option expose. However the target class is `AbstractMessageProducingHandler`. To avoid code duplication we reuse an existing `outputChannel` internally for that `AsyncHandler`.

In the XML parser we just remap one to another:

```
IntegrationNamespaceUtils.setReferenceIfAttributeDefined(builder, element, "success-channel", "outputChannel");
```

You probably don't see anything in logs because you need to adjust logging config respectively for the appropriate category and level.

**UPDATE**

According my testing this is definitely not possible to configure such a component with XML DSL within the `<chain>`. That `<int-aws:sqs-outbound-channel-adapter>` has to be presented outside of the `<chain>`.

Consider to more your configuration to Java DSL instead: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.3.2.RELEASE/reference/html/dsl.html#java-dsl.

Comment: I think the issue is that my <int-aws:sqs-outbound-channel-adapter> is inside a <int:chain with no output channel>. Hence the message is not routed to the success-channel. It(success-channel) works only when I add an output-channel on the chain.How to handle this scenario without creating an output channel on the <int:chain>?

Comment: Move it outside of the `chain`. Would be great to see your configuration for confirmation. Otherwise it’s all speculation

Comment: I have added the config via EDIT to the main question, request you to review it.

Comment: OK. Anyway. How does it work if it is configured outside of the `chain`?

Comment: See an UPDATE in my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Outside the 'chain' it works fine. I will try the DSL approach. Just a thought - as an enhancement should the framework fallback to create a new success-channel when no existing output channel is found?

Comment: It’s not related. The chain has a logic to set its internal channels into handlers for forwarding. So, whatever we provide is overridden